# Update button text in monodroid after tcp/ip message

Tags: button, dynamic, tcp, xamarin.android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [monodroid Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097729/monodroid-timer)

I'm communicating with a tcp/ip server. The server sends a message with a new label for the button. 
The button text is changed but does not update. Only when I clicked the button it will update itself
Any suggestions?

Found it, use:

```
private void OnTimeEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    RunOnUiThread(delegate {
        txv1.Text = count.ToString ();
        count++;
    });
}
```

See thread: [monodroid Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097729/monodroid-timer/7099330#7099330)

Comment: If the thread you found answered your question, please make an actual answer to your own question and write what the solution was there, still linking to the source - then mark it as answered.